# Cors error consuming API from React front-end with AAD authentication

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, cors

I've used the [Yeoman Teams App Generator](https://github.com/pnp/generator-teams) to generate a boilerplate ReactJS Teams app with built-in Azure AD Single Sign-ON. 
This works. The Teams app authenticates with Azure AD (in the background) and pulls up some data from my user profile.

Now I want this Teams app to consume an API. This API is an ASP.NET Core website that uses the same AAD app for authentication.
However, when I try to fetch data from this API in the Teams app, it fails with the error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx/oauth2/authorize?client_id=xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44391%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=xxx' 
(redirected from 'https://localhost:44391/User') from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I've checked the settings in the AAD app and can't find anything wrong there.

The react code is:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Provider, Flex, Text, Button, Header } from "@fluentui/react-northstar";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useTeams } from "msteams-react-base-component";
import * as microsoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";

/**
 * Implementation of the Telefoonboek content page
 */
export const TelefoonboekTab = () => {

    const [{ inTeams, theme, context }] = useTeams();
    const [entityId, setEntityId] = useState<string | undefined>();
    const [name, setName] = useState<string>();
    const [error, setError] = useState<string>();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (inTeams === true) {
            microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken({
                successCallback: (token: string) => {
                    const decoded: { [key: string]: any; } = jwtDecode(token) as { [key: string]: any; };
                    setName(decoded!.name);
                    microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifySuccess();
                },
                failureCallback: (message: string) => {
                    setError(message);
                    microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifyFailure({
                        reason: microsoftTeams.appInitialization.FailedReason.AuthFailed,
                        message
                    });
                },
                resources: [process.env.TELEFOONBOEK_APP_URI as string]
            });
        } else {
            setEntityId("Not in Microsoft Teams");
        }
    }, [inTeams]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (context) {
            setEntityId(context.entityId);
        }
    }, [context]);

    fetch("/User")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));

    /**
     * The render() method to create the UI of the tab
     */
    return (
        <Provider theme={theme}>
            <Flex fill={true} column styles={{
                padding: ".8rem 0 .8rem .5rem"
            }}>
                <Flex.Item>
                    <Header content="This is your tab" />
                </Flex.Item>
                <Flex.Item>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <Text content={`Hello ${name}`} />
                        </div>
                        {error && <div><Text content={`An SSO error occurred ${error}`} /></div>}

                        <div>
                            <Button onClick={() => alert("It worked!")}>A sample button</Button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Flex.Item>
                <Flex.Item styles={{
                    padding: ".8rem 0 .8rem .5rem"
                }}>
                    <Text size="smaller" content="(C) Copyright Zetacom" />
                </Flex.Item>
            </Flex>
        </Provider>
    );
};
```

The API startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using System;

namespace UserPresence
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private static readonly string CustomApiScheme = "CustomApiScheme";
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: "CorsPolicy",
                                  builder =>
                                  {
                                      builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                                  });
            });

            //ConfigureAuthentication(services);

            services.AddDbContext<dbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddTransient<UserModel>();

            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });

            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            });
        }

        private void ConfigureAuthentication(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = AzureADDefaults.CookieScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CustomApiScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = AzureADDefaults.CookieScheme;
            })
            .AddAzureAD(options =>
            {
                Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
            })
            .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, CustomApiAuthenticationHandler>(CustomApiScheme, options => { });

            services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(AzureADDefaults.CookieScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
                options.Cookie.MaxAge = new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0);
            });

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";         // Microsoft identity platform
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false; // accept several tenants (here simplified)
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
            
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

I've added 'AllowAnyOrigin' etc on the API.
Now the error in Teams is:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44391%2Fsignin-oidc&xxx' 
(redirected from 'https://xxxx.eu.ngrok.io/User') from origin 'https://xxxx.eu.ngrok.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: Pls show a startup  code  of API project

Comment: I've added the startup.cs.

Comment: Try 'builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();'  ? @CJScholten

Comment: After adding that, the error changes (see edit)

Comment: @CJScholten I think this may has some relationship with ngrok. Here's an [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#preflight-requests) mentioned this 'preflight request' error. And I think if you test in product environment, it won't appear, at least in my side it is. I test my code when I use ngrok, it burst out cors error, and after deploying to azure app service, it worked.

Comment: I noticed that at first, the error you provided is  localhost:44391, and the updated error is ngrok.io.

Answer (score 0):

Your error resulted from CORS policy, and I tested in my side
with `builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();` then it worked.

But not with ngrok, I deployed my MVC program to azure app service.